# How to fix a "subscript out of range" error for vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, runtime-error

Out of range error for vectors in my code. What can I do to stop the error? I've checked so many forums.

I've already done some basic trials to see if something else was the problem. Starting at 0. Wrote the code from scratch again. Used other IDEs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "graph.h"
using namespace std;

graph::graph() {
    count = 0;
}
void graph::addVertex(const Node node) {
    vertices.push_back(node);
    count++;
}
void graph::addEdge(const char from, const char to) {
    vertices[from].edges.push_back(to);
    vertices[to].edges.push_back(from);
}
void graph::print() {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (i < vertices.size()) {
        cout << vertices[i].name << "->";
        if (vertices[i].edges.size() > 0)
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < vertices[i].edges.size(); j++)
                cout << vertices[i].edges[j];
        cout << endl;
        i++;
    }
```

Results always lead me to line 1733 of the vector file, and I'm unsure if more error will come after fixing the error.

Comment: You will want to go up the call stack (check documentation of your IDE for how to do that) until you until you end up at the point where your code called the vector code and then figure out why the index at that point is wrong.

Comment: My advice is to use a debugger. If you think you know what  vector has an out of bounds access use .at(index) instead of [index] to get it the vector to throw an excretion. In a debugger like the one in Visual Stuido you can have it break on that exception and you will know the exact line that had the out of bounds access.

Comment: Don't allow the index to get out of range. It's that easy. Individually all of the functions look good except `addEdge` where `from` or `to` could be out of range. We have no way of knowing for sure without a better example. From your description, It looks like the program is being halted by a debugger. Check the call stack or backtrace to see which of your functions was the last one called before the error. That will likely be the place to start your investigating.

Comment: *I've already done some basic trials to see if something else was the problem.* -- Your program has bugs.  It has nothing to do with a "bad compiler" or IDE.  I guess you were to believe that if your program happens to compile successfully, it will run without error.  That is not how this works -- if you compile successfully, all that means is that your program has no syntax errors.  Your program can still have logical errors, and obviously your program has logical errors that you need to fix.

Comment: I agree with @user4581301 addEdge() seems to be the only code shown that could cause a problem.

Comment: `vertices[from].edges.push_back(to);` -- What if `from` is a wild value (out of range)?  Similarly, `vertices[to].edges.push_back(from);` -- What if `to` is a wild, out of range value?

Comment: Consider temporarily inserting an assert just before the use of from (and the use of to).  The assert should check that 'from' (and 'to') is in range 0 .. (vertices.size()-1).  If it fires in normal operation, then enter the debugger, and set a breakpoint on the line where the assert fires, and run.  At that breakpint, check each value, climb the stack (up) and identify where the indexes go wrong.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code and find your logic error that's causing you to go outside the bounds. Recompiling a million times isn't gong to change anything - you have an error in your code logic, and you need to identify it before you can fix it. We can't do that for you, because we don't have the rest of your code or the input values you're using. It's never too early to learn to use the debugger; it's one of the most powerful tools in a developer's toolkit, and the sooner you learn to use it the better. :-)

Comment: Also, you don't need to debug into the vector source. The problem will be in your own code, so you can just set a breakpoint there (I'd start at the `while` line) and step through until the error happens, and then you can figure out why it did.

Comment: ***1733 of the vector file*** you should be able to switch the callstack to your code. That should tell you what part of your code that has the out of bounds access.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everybody's responses, especially @user4581301, I messed around with it, and the output comes out as desired with this replacement for the addEdge function.

```
void graph::addEdge(const char from, const char to) {
    if (vertices.size() == 0)
        return;
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
        if (vertices[i].name == from)
            vertices[i].edges.push_back(to);
        if (vertices[i].name == to)
            vertices[i].edges.push_back(from);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not completely safe. It eliminates the fear of out-of bounds access, but runs the risk of a messy screw-up later if the `to` or `from` is not found. Alternative that will save a lot of spinning around looking for nodes: [`std::unordered_map<Node> vertices`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). Depending on the complexity of `Node` You may be able to take advantage of `unordered_map`'s ability to create a slot that's missing to eliminate `Node` and `addVertex`.